# How to focus on the newly added HTML element

Tags: angular, typescript

This my HTML Template.

```
<div
        cdkDropList
        class="document-columns__list list"
        (cdkDropListDropped)="dragDrop($event)"
    >
        <div
            cdkDrag
            class="list__box"
            *ngFor="let column of columns; let i = index"
            (click)="selectColumn(column)"
            [class.list__box_selected]="column === selectedColumn"
        >
            <div class="list__placeholder" *cdkDragPlaceholder></div>
            <div class="list__content">
                <div class="list__name">
                    {{column.col_num}}. {{column.title}}
                </div>
                <div class="list__type">
                    {{getType(column)?.title}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <p-button
                class="list__button"
                icon="pi pi-trash"
                styleClass="p-button-danger p-button-outlined"
                [disabled]="columns.length === 1"
                (click)="deleteColumn(column)"
            ></p-button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="document-columns__button">
        <p-button
            styleClass="p-button-secondary p-button-outlined"
            (click)="addNewColumn()"
            label="Add column"
            icon="pi pi-plus"
            iconPos="left"
        >
        </p-button>
    </div>
```

This my TS code.

```
 public addNewColumn(): void {
    const arrayLength: number = this.columns.length + 1;
    this.columns.push({
        col_num: arrayLength,
        type_id: TypeId.Number,
        title: 'New Column',
    });
    this.columnsChanged.emit(this.columns);
    this.recalculateColumnNumbers();
}
```

When I click the add column button. A new element is created in the array. The template is redrawn with a new element. I want to focus on it after that. How to do it? I've tried this code, but it doesn't work.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.document-columns__list:last-child').focus();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just focus the last element you added in your `addNewColumn` method.
You just need to wait until the element in rendered in the dom. So in my example below I just postponed the focus action using `setTimeout`
It is always recommended to use the angular way to query an html element. So I just used [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) decorator.

```
@ViewChildren('element', { read: ElementRef }) elements: QueryList<ElementRef>;

 public addNewColumn(): void {
....
  setTimeout(() => 
    this.elements.last.nativeElement.focus()
    );
}
```

In your template you should just put a [template variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) #element on the element you want to focus to allow the component class to get access to it.

```
<div #element></div>
```

Here is a working example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nszzdt

Comment: ``` setTimeout(() =>{
            this.elements.last.nativeElement.click();
        }```

Comment: Trigger element click is not the same as focusing the element. When you click on a certain type of element it will be focused.
It depends on the element type. If it's a focusable element like HTMLButtonElement or HTMLInputElement then it's recommended to use the standard focus method.

Comment: Thanks, Mehyar Sawas!

Answer (score 0):

```
@ViewChildren('element', { read: ElementRef }) public elements!: QueryList<ElementRef>;

public addNewColumn(): void {
    const arrayLength: number = this.columns.length + 1;
    this.columns.push({
        col_num: arrayLength,
        type_id: TypeId.Number,
        title: 'Add column',
    });
    this.columnsChanged.emit(this.columns);
    this.recalculateColumnNumbers();
    setTimeout(() => this.elements.last.nativeElement.click());
}
```